# Python Beautifulsoup dropdown menu

Tags: python

I am trying to select current month in the dropdown menu, but I am not sure Beautifulsoup is like Selenium, which I should 'click' search button to get the result, and do not know how to do that in Beautifulsoup, since the website is not opening as selenium, I cannot observe the process whether the month is selected, I use:

```
html_link = 'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = now.month
soup.select('(option["{}"])'.format(month))
FourDaysAgo = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 4))
FourDaysAgo_day = FourDaysAgo.day
now = datetime.date.today()
today = now.day
d = range(FourDaysAgo_day,today)
```

May I know how could I SELECT the month and then click for results? Many thanks!

Comment: Beautifulsoup is for parsing the HTML, not for performing actions on it.

Comment: Beauifulsoup is used for scraping. It doesn't have any clicking functionality. You could try using the get.request of the click and passing that through BS.

Comment: also to add on, beautiful soup does not have any browser like functionalities, it is used to scrape content from static pages and does not have any capabilities to work with dynamic objects such as dropdowns etc. to work with that you have to manually enter some test parameters and then do some research on the url it goes to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some work with the link provided and looks like you can select month and year just by passing the parameters as get request parameters.

```py
def get_page(month: int, year: int):
    uri = f'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US&Month={str(month).rjust(2, '0')}&Year={year}'
    return requests.get(uri)
```

and now you can use the above function to get the webpage and then you can scrape
data from it.

Note: January starts from number 1

Comment: thank you so much! but may I ask if could I delete .rjust(2, '0')? does it mean fill two 0s?

Comment: no as per i saw, it  appended 0 before the number 4 when i entered march 2018. so i thought i will use rjust to make sure the length is 2 and when the length is 1 it appends a single 0 to the start. rjust means adjust to right with the width 2 and fill character '0'